# jQuery toggle no animation needed

Tags: jquery, animation

May i blind or is there no parameter, option or whatever to disable the animations for:

.toggle()

I just want to show() and hide() them via toggle() but every toggle i use slideToggle, fadeToggle or even the normal toggle are with an animation.

How to "remove" them?

Comment: As long as you don't provide a duration to toggle, it should be immediate. Show us your code please.

Comment: i use a simple click handler with a .toggle() on an element. why the down votes???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make sure the parameter to toggle() resolves to true, not to 1.

```
toggle(1); // animation 
toggle(true); // no animation.
```

Comment: This did not work for me. setting toggle(true) meant I could only show the content not hide it again.

Answer (score 8):

toggle() is immediate if no arguments are supplied.

slideToggle() and fadeToggle() uses default values for the animation, to make them immediate, pass the value '0';

These all do the same, just shows and hides the element:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    ToggleElement.toggle();
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
    ToggleElement.slideToggle(0);
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
    ToggleElement.fadeToggle(0);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nmXDm/)

There is however no reason to use the bottom two without animations, as that sort of defeats the point.

A little faster would be to just use javascripts native `element.style.display = 'none'/'block'` in an if / else statement.

Answer (score 4):

Just use toggle with no arguments, and it should be immediate.

From the docs:

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility
>   of elements:
>
> ```
> $('.target').toggle();
> ```

Comment: try yourself... .toggle() with no arguments not only toggles show or hide... theres also a height and width animation with a duration. i know the docu its wrong. im using the last stable jquery version.

Comment: I did try it myself before posting in jsfiddle using jQuery 1.7, and it toggled visibility

Answer (score 3):

You could always supply your own toggle function:

```
$.fn.quicktoggle = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':visible')) {
            $this.hide();
        } else {
            $this.show();
        }
    });
    return this;
};
```

Comment: I think you have an extra `)` at last

Answer (score 2):

Just turn off the effects

```
jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more 'imposing' method would be to override the functions, if you want to easily replace all instances in your code.

```
$.fn.slideToggle = function(duration, callback ) {
    duration = 0;
    callback = callback || function(){};
    this.toggle(duration, callback);
};

$.fn.fadeToggle = function(duration, callback) {
    duration = 0;
    callback = callback || function(){};
    this.toggle(duration, callback);
};
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bChVe/3/

Comment: Hmmm... this way has trouble with duration arguments and callbacks... edit in a sec

Comment: Edited with proper callbacks and force duration to 0

Comment: I don't _think_ you have to wrap `$(this)` inside a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.clk').click(function(){

if(document.getElementById("ID").className == "p-cap hide")
{
   document.getElementById("ID").className = "p-cap show";
}
else
{
   document.getElementById("ID").className = "p-cap hide";
}

});
```

```css
.p-cap { height:100px; width:100px; background :red; float:left; }

.clk { height:100px; width:100px; background :green; float:left; }

.hide { display: none; }

.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clk"></div>
<div id="ID" class="p-cap hide"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, can you please post some text explaining why your answer is correct. Pleas see [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).